# GROUP BY in django ORM with synthetic attributes

Tags: django, django-orm

Transforming my problem to a simpler domain, suppose I have inherited a django app with a data model representing test grades as letters ("A+", "A", "A-", "B+", etc), and I want to report grade averages as percentages, where {"A+": 100, "A": 95, ...}.

toy model:

```
class TestGrade(models.Model):
  student = ForeignKey(Student)
  letter_grade = CharField()
  course = ForeignKey(Course)
```

(assume that changing the model and doing a migration - the sensible solution - is off the table, perhaps because we want to have the flexibility to apply different mappings of letter grade to numeric score)

To report these out, I get the grades for a given course using the obvious query, and then apply a case statement based on the mapping above, something like

```
grades.annotate(score=Case(When(letter_grade="A+", then=Value(100)), 
                           When(letter_grade="A", then=Value(95)),
                           ...
                           default=Value(0),
                           output_field=IntegerField)))
```

Now, I'd like to do a GROUP BY on students and report out their average grade. Unfortunately the standard djangonic way to do a GROUP BY,

```
grades.values("student_id").annotate(Avg('score'))
```

dies horribly with `KeyError: 'score'`

```
grades.values("student_id", "score").annotate(Avg('score'))
```

does not die horribly, but of course it groups by the tuple of id and score, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to group by student_id and annotate with the average of a synthetic value?

Obviously, I can do this in python, but for the usual reasons I'd like to do this in the ORM if it is reasonably possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about putting this logic on the model? This makes the business logic available anywhere the `Student` object is. Consider:

```
class Student(models.Model)
    ...

    @property
    def average_test_grade(self):
        return self.testgrade_set.all().annotate(
            score=Case(
                When(letter_grade="A", then=Value(100)),
                When(letter_grade="A-", then=Value(90)),
                When(letter_grade="B+", then=Value(89)),
                When(letter_grade="B-", then=Value(80)),
                default=Value(0),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ).aggregate(Avg('score'))
```

Then in your `views.py` you can reduce the number of queries with `.prefetch_related()`:

```
students = Student.objects.prefetch_related('testgrade_set').all()
```

and finally in the template or potentially elsewhere:

```
<ul>
{% for student in students %}
<li>{{ student.average_test_grade }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't help me a lot with reporting - this is still imposing one query per student, and I have to come out of the ORM into python world to use it. Thanks, though.